# I am starting web development with Tornado. Need some beginner assistance

Tags: web-applications, tornado

Sorry for the long question, but I'm confused, and don't know exactly what I need.  So please read through the entire question before posting anything so you can get a better idea.

So, I'm a software engineering co-op student on a work term, and my boss wants me to develop a web application using Tornado.  I've done some html and css in high school, but this is really out of my element.

Tornado has hardly any tutorials on how to get started.  Sure, there's a hello world example, but then they throw out some chat application, that in my case, may as well be written in binary.

I know how to use tornado to render a page and send data as a parameter.  I can then use that data to do some logic within the webpage itself (i.e. database requests, loops,...)  I now know enough Javascript to call functions to write text or make alerts.

Now the problem arises where I want to go to another of my html pages.  Sure, I can use Javascript, or html to go to an external site (i.e. Google), but if I try to go to a relative document in the same directory, I just get a 404.  My supervisor wants me to investigate using POST and GET requests to make calls to my Tornado Server RequestHandler (so I can just call render again), but I just can't figure out how to make/receive that request.

In the end, there are three main questions:

- What other languages should I know to properly use Tornado?

  - I know html, xslt, css, some JS, SQL, json
  - I don't want to become a web guru; I just want the basics
- How do I make a GET/POST request on my tornado handler?
- How do I redirect to a relative html page?

This is my handler that I am using:

```
class MainHandler(RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        print 'get...',
        self.render('test.html', data = Data())
        print 'done'


    def post(self):
        print 'post...',
        pass
        print 'done'
```

EDIT:
I've learned a bit more about RequestHandlers now, but I have no idea what the proper way of doing them is.  I have this RequestHandler handling request for two pages, but I would like to be able to use one handler for each page, and I have no idea if I'm interpreting the arguments the best way.  I also have no idea how to have arguments go to the *args parameter.

```
def get(self, *args, ** kwargs):
    print 'get:', args, kwargs, 'Handling:',

    if len(self.get_arguments('user')) > 0:
        print 'user'
        self.render('page2.html', user = self.get_arguments('user')[0])
    elif len(self.get_arguments('page')):
        print 'specific page:', self.get_argument('page')
        self.render(self.get_argument('page'), data = Data())
    else:
        print 'default'
        self.render('test.html', data = Data())
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you define your application you can specify your template directory and your static files directory:

```python
import Settings

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
        ]
        settings = {
            "template_path":Settings.TEMPLATE_PATH,
            "static_path":Settings.STATIC_PATH,
            "debug":Settings.DEBUG
        }
        tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, handlers, **settings)
```

you can define a Settings.py

```python
import os
DEBUG = True
DIRNAME = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'static')
TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(DIRNAME, 'template')
```

[image]

When you try to reach your tornado start url:

```
http://localhost:port/
```

Tornado execute your get method in your MainHandler. Then Tornado render test.html page. But you have to specify the TEMPLATE_PATH to indicate Tornado where it can get this template.

```python
class MainHandler(RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        print 'get...',
        self.render('test.html', data = Data())
        print 'done'
```

To make a redirection in get or post method in yours handlers, you can add this:

```python
self.redirect("/my_new_page.html")
```

To propely use Tornado you may understrand how web applications work. client / server communication, understand HTML verbs and more important try and try

Comment: Ah, thank you.  That helps a lot.  I'm starting to figure out how to intercept the form get requests now, too.

Comment: Do you know of any resources I could use to learn more about RequestHandlers?  Specifically, I'd like to learn how to assign a page a new RequestHandler, and the best practice for building get requests to request new pages.  Once again, I feel like there's a level of understanding that I'm expected to know to be using Tornado, but I just don't have it.

Comment: I added another part to the question at the end.

Comment: I make a new answer, I hope it will help you